# How to position horizontally centered elements at top, middle and bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to position a horizontally centered element at the top, a horizontally centered at the bottom and an element at the center of the screen?[image: Layout]

Comment: Use flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the height of the html and body to 100%, then use flexbox with `flex-direction: column;` to make it operate vertically, and `justify-content: space-between;` to do the spacing.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}
body>* {
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div>Element 2</div>
  <div>Element 3</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally align center a block element (like paragraph inside div) as well as Text, use margin: auto;

```
<style>
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
.centerText {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
</style>

<div class="center">
  <p>This Element is Aligned Horizontally Center !</p>
</div>

<div class="centerText">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The display: grid can also be used to attain the desire. [Grid-Template-Rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) and [Grid-Template-Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) can be used to set the appropriate size for each row and column, respectively. In this case, the fractional unit Fr stands for one part of the available space (1fr). For more information on fr, visit this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-css-grid-layout-fr-unit).

```
<style>
        html,body{height: 100%;}
        .wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 100px);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            grid-gap: 20px;
            align-content:space-between;
            justify-content: space-around;
          }
        
          .item1{
            background-color:green ;
          }

          .item2{
            background-color: blue;
          }

          .item3{
            background-color: blueviolet;
          }
          
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
      </div>
</body>
```